# How to subtract two data entries in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

In my database, there is one table containing (ID, Name, Time, Type)

```
ID     Name    Time        Type
1      Osama   12:15 AM    IN
2      Osama   12:20 AM    OUT
3      Osama   14:15 AM    IN
4      Osama   14:20 AM    OUT
```

I need to construct a query to output the time-difference (OUT-IN)

```
Name, OUT-IN
```

Example:

```
Osama, 5
Osama, 5
```

Answer (score 2):

The `TestData` CTE here is purely for testing purposes. Also, I note that there is an error your data. Last I checked `14:15 AM` isn't a valid time. It is either `14:15` (via 24 hr clock) or `2:15 AM` (via 12 hr clock). Also, this solution would require SQL Server 2005 or later.

```
With TestData As
    (
    Select 1 As Id, 'Osama' As Name, '12:15' As Time, 'IN' As Type
    Union All Select 2, 'Osama', '12:20', 'OUT'
    Union All Select 3, 'Osama', '14:15', 'IN'
    Union All Select 4, 'Osama', '14:20', 'OUT'
    )
    , CheckInCheckOut As
    (
    Select Id, Name, Time, Type
        , Row_Number() Over ( Partition By Name, Type Order By Time ) As Num
    From TestData
    )
Select C1.Name
    , DateDiff( mi, CAST(C1.Time as datetime), Cast(C2.Time As datetime) ) As [OUT-IN]
From CheckInCheckOut As C1
    Join CheckInCheckOut As C2
        On C2.Name = C1.Name
            And C2.Type = 'OUT'
            And C2.Num = C1.Num 
Where C1.Type = 'IN'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do Max(TimeRecorded) if you are ok with assuming your times are sequential.  This assumes your Ids are sequential.  You can control either of those with check constraints.

```
declare @test table (
    Id int, Name varchar(50), TimeRecorded time, TypeOfTimeRecording varchar(3)
)

insert into @test values (1, 'Osama', CONVERT(time, '12:15'), 'IN')
insert into @test values (2, 'Osama', CONVERT(time, '12:20'), 'OUT')
insert into @test values (3, 'Osama', CONVERT(time, '12:25'), 'IN')
insert into @test values (4, 'Osama', CONVERT(time, '12:30'), 'OUT')

 select testOut.Name
        ,testOut.TimeRecorded
        ,testIn.TimeRecorded
        ,DATEDIFF(minute, testIn.TimeRecorded, testOut.TimeRecorded) as [Out - In]
   from @test testOut
            inner join
        @test testIn    on testIn.Id = (select MAX(Id) from @test where Name = testOut.Name and Id < testOut.Id and TypeOfTimeRecording = 'IN')
  where testOut.TypeOfTimeRecording = 'OUT'
```